# Japanese movie featuring a woman turning into a motorcycle

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

Sometime in the late 90s I saw a Japanese movie on video, then quite new, which I though was called Tetsuo. I don't remember much of the movie, except for a short fragment (1 or 2 minutes) in which a woman turns into a motorcycle. The fragment was quite dark, maybe black and white, but I'm not certain of that, and it was certainly an intense, and probably distressing experience for the woman.

It was certainly not a mainstream movie, I don't think it was shown in theaters in the Netherlands, where I saw it, at the time, but I did read some review or another, maybe in the Opscene or the Vera krant, Dutch alternative (mostly music) magazines. I think I remember reading specifically about that fragment, so probably it is among the more memorable scenes in the film.

I searched for that fragment the other day, but I couldn't find it, moreover from the description of Tetsuo I thought that it didn't quite fit. It is quite possible that I saw both films around the same time, and mixed them up. Maybe even to the extent that it wasn't a Japanese movie at all, though that would certainly surprise me.

Does anyone know what movie it could have been?

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please see our [FAQ on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any additional details you can think of.

Comment: Not https://youtu.be/O9DDOZ-Ve5o?t=564?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Haha, nice one, but certainly not!

Comment: *Tetsuo* did receive a sequel, *Tetsuo 2: Body Hammer*. Did the film involve a lot of wires sprouting out of the affected characters?

Comment: @doetoe Could you describe transformation process? How that woman looked like? And motorbyke?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I have certainly heard the title of the sequel. The lack of color is close to what I remember from that scene as well, but I don't think it was that one either...

Comment: https://collider.com/body-horror-tetsuo-the-iron-man/#:~:text=There's%20no%20doubt%20that%20Tetsuo,would%20be%20an%20atrocious%20understatement

Comment: The title of the question reminded me that it happened in the game Final Fantasy XIII, which is 20 years too late.